# Rails 6 Routes Subdomain

Tags: routes, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

I am working on setting up a Subdomain system on my Rails project (Rails 6, Ruby 2.6.6).

I have the subdomain system working fine using the following

```
constraints subdomain: 'chef' do
  devise_for :chefs, controllers: { registrations: 'chefs/registrations' },
  resources :chefs do
    resources :chef_profiles
  end
end
```

but I want to change the way the URI are presented.

At the moment if I want to view a `chef_profile` - the route is `chef.domain.com/chefs/:id/chef_profile/:id` what I'd like it to be is `chef.domain.com/chef_name`

any ideas on how I can change the way the nested works? tried doing `as: :...` but don't know what to put in the `as` part.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way without hijacking the rest of your routes would be to just use a `get` matcher:

```
constraints subdomain: 'chef' do 
  get "/:chef_name", to: "chef_profiles#show", chef_name: /-?[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-\_]*/i
end
```

You may need to adjust the `chef_name` regex to suit your pattern.